# Defining an AnsiString matrix in Borland C++ builder without knowing the size

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I have the following code:

```
int cl = value1;
int fl = value2;
AnsiString **mat = NULL;
mat = (AnsiString **)malloc(sizeof(AnsiString)*fl);
for(int i=0; i < fl; i++) mat[i]=(AnsiString *)malloc(sizeof(AnsiString)*cl);
int count = 0;
for (int f=0; f<fl; f++){
      for (int c=0; c<cl; c++){
          if (count < str.Length()) mat[f][c]=str[++count];
          else mat[f][c]='X';
      }
}
```

But it is not working.  I read several "how to's" but I can't find the right way to do it.

I'm pretty noob with this malloc thing so any advice/help will be apreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) have many things, including many [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Use of the standard library will greatly help you as a C++ programmer.

Comment: Oh, and check your use of the `sizeof` operator. `sizeof(AnsiString)` will most likely not be the same as `sizeof(AnsiString*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never allocate non-POD objects using malloc, like you are:

```
mat[i]=(AnsiString *)malloc(sizeof(AnsiString)*cl)
```

The constructor of the object won't be called (you would have to call it manually afterwards using the **placement new** operator). The line above is just pleading for a memory error.

Use the `new[]` operator instead:

```
AnsiString **mat = mat = new AnsiString*[fl];
for(int i=0; i < fl; i++) mat[i] = new AnsiString[cl];
```

You can still access an object using `mat[m][n]`, where `m` is a row number and `n` is a column number.

Don't forget to free the memory using `delete[]` when done:

```
for(int i=0; i < fl; i++) delete[] mat[i];
delete[] mat;
```

However, using `new[]`/`delete[]` like this is still error prone if you are not careful.  I recommend you to use a `std::vector` instead, and let it manage all of the memory for you:

```
std::vector< std::vector<AnsiString> > mat( f1 );
for( i = 0; i < f1; ++i ) mat[i].resize( c1 );
```

You can still access an object using `mat[m][n]`, but you don't have to worry about freeing anything as it will free itself automatically when it goes out of scope.